# Socks version 5 protocol

Tags: network-protocols

Can someone point me the steps in using the socks 5 protocol,i read about it,but i want to be sure i am doing it corect because it doesnt work for my proxy server. First the client sends me a packet with the version,number of methods and the methods,i send back, a packet with the version and then the method i choosed. Then it sends me a packet with the version, command, reserved,type of address, dest adress, dest port(for exameple google.com 80) i send back a packet with the version,request granted, reserved, adress type, dest address, dest port(again gooogle.com 80). And then what is the next step ? To call Connect ?

Comment: You do have the SOCKS5 specification at hand, right?

Comment: after i send the last packet,then i will call directly coonect ?

Comment: Take some client that support SOCKS 5, some SOCKS proxy server and Ethereal sniffer, and study the communication going between the client and SOCKS proxy

Answer (score 0):

You must open a network stream to the request's target and, once you sent the reply packet, tunnel all TCP traffic from request's target to the initial request link (both sides)